# Highlighting current page in a nav menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uinavigationbar

I looked online to see various approaches of highlighting a current menu navigation with Jquery, and I came across the bit of code below. The code works perfectly but I don't quite understand the second line and I was wondering if one of you could explain it please.

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
$("#mainMenu").find("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass("current");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try these after `var url` statement. `alert(url.lastIndexOf("/"));` and `alert(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1));`

Answer (score 4):

```
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

simply grabs the very last segment of the url.  For example if the url were

```
foo.com/module/submodule
```

it would return `submodule`

It does this by finding the last index of `/`, and then passing *1 + that* to `substr`.

From your comment of `The part that got me confused was the '+1' at the end`, note that substr takes the index at which **the substring starts**.  You don't want to start the substring at `/`, so 1 is added so that the substring will start at the character immediately after the last `/`.

And for completeness, the whole remainder of the url is returned since no second parameter is passed to substr.  If a second parameter had been passed, then only that number of characters would have been returned.

[More info on substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: Thanks makes sense. The part that got me confused was the '+1' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

The `substr()` method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.

The `lastIndexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the last occurrence of the specified value, or -1 if not found. The calling string is searched backward, starting at 0 by default.

Comment: Seems like it should be in comment.

Answer (score 0):

var url returns a string value, and a string is an array of characters.  Given that it's an array, each character has a position.

```
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

What we're doing is reading the `url` value and getting a substring of it starting right after the last `/` of the url, til the end of the value.

To learn more, read up here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

And here's a little fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/gd5Xr/

Answer (score 0):

The second line in your solution trims the full current url from last `/`.

- `substr()` = this trims the given string, in this case - full url.
- `lastIndexOf()` = this method brings index integer of the given param. In this
  case from given url, index number of last `/`.
- +1 for `substr` is just to avoid the last `/` from new trimmed value.